# Spring Security Custom AuthenticationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, exception, spring-security-oauth2

I am working with Spring Security. I want to implement my custom exception message same like **UsernameNotFoundException** used by spring security from **message.property** file as **AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Bad credentials**

My custom exception is as below:

```
public class CustomUsernameNotFoundException extends AuthenticationException {
public CustomUsernameNotFoundException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
}
public CustomUsernameNotFoundException(String msg, Throwable t) {
    super(msg, t);
}
```

}

How can I configure and handle custom exception in spring security.

Note: please not suggest to update message on messages.properties which will used  by spring security by default.

Comment: Are you using Jersey as well? Answers might vary if you use spring mvc or jersey

Comment: working with Spring Boot

Comment: [spring-security-custom-access-denied-page](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-access-denied-page) could help you

Comment: @Dirk Deyne: I am not working with web page but using oauth2 for rest API